# Docker Swarm : How to setup multiple containers on same volume

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, docker-swarm, docker-volume

Am using Docker 1.12.2 build bb80604 with swarm enabled

I have

- a swarm cluster with 2 leader & 3 slave nodes.
- named volume on each on slave & leader nodes.
- Elistacsearch running on 2 master servers

Volume create command

> docker volume create -d local-persist -o
>   mountpoint=/data/docker/swarm/elasticsearch --name esvolume

Now when i run docker service create command to create 5 replicas of Elasticsearch, 3 nodes start (1 on each slave server) whereas remaining 2 replicas fails

```
docker service create --replicas 5 --name esdata \
--restart-max-attempts 5 --network myesnetwork \
-e CLUSTER_NAME=swarmescluster \
-e MASTER_NODES=esmaster \
--mount type=volume,src=esvolume,dst=/var/lib/elasticsearch \
--mount type=volume,src=esvolume,dst=/var/log/elasticsearch \
myimagename
```

Error for failure is

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: **failed to obtain node
>   locks, tried [[/var/lib/elasticsearch/swarmescluster]]** with lock id
>   [0]; maybe these locations are not writable or multiple nodes were
>   started without increasing [node.max_local_storage_nodes] (was [1])?
>           at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.(NodeEnvironment.java:259)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.(Node.java:240) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.(Node.java:220) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.(Bootstrap.java:191)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:191)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:286)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]

**Questions**

1. How can I configure replicas to write to same path or dynamic path (I need persistent data)
2. If I want to set value of 'node.max_local_storage_nodes' when a replica is created, how i do it an runtime?